# How to Access an Array using a String Name (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

I have a program that is trying to randomly select something by starting at the main category and working its way down. For example, it starts at the first array and chooses one of 5 items. From there, I want it to locate the array associated with that item. (there are 5 arrays, one for each item in the original array)

```js
mainArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];

item1Array = [];
item2Array = [];
item3Array = [];
item4Array = [];
item5Array = [];

fucntion choose() {
  var choice1 = mainArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * mainArray.length)];
  
  
}
```

I tried concatenating the word "Array" onto choice1 and choosing an item from that, but it chooses a random letter from the string "itemXArray" rather than choosing a random item from the array.

TLDR: How do I access a different array based on a result from a previous one? Keep in mind, I want to do this multiple layers deep. (4 to be exact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not an array but an Object though. You can access the values in an Object via their corresponding keys. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

```
let itemsArray = {
    "item1Array" : [1],
    "item2Array" : [2],
    "item3Array" : [3]
}

let name = "item1"


itemsArray[`${name}Array`]

// > [1]
```

Comment: So I have swapped over to using objects instead. My problem is that I have a bunch of objects now named xDescriptions, yDescriptions, zDescriptions, etc. I have pulled the x, y, or z randomly into a variable. Now I need to reach into the associated descriptions object by combining that variable with the word "Descriptions", but I can't seem to figure out how.

displayName = (variable + 'Display')[variable];

This is what I am trying, but by putting Display as a string, it once again makes the first part a string, and just pulls a random letter from that. Can you help me?

Comment: @ WyWyGuy Just create a new object with objects to be selected (e.g. `variable + 'Display'`) as members. For example, create object `const displayObjs = {"xDisplay": xObj, "yDisplay": yObj};` and select them by `displayObj = displayObjs[variable + 'Display']`. Then you can further select values in `xObj` by `displayName = displayObj[variable]`, or directly with `displayName = displayObjs[variable1 + 'Display'][variable2]`.

Comment: @ SdtElectronics
So I get what you are saying, and I have done that. My problem is, I have a multi-level chain structure it goes down. So on the first level, this works great. I have one of 5 items randomly selected and the corresponding display name chosen. But each of those 5 objects has their own separate subcategory. 5 subcategories, 5 sub display names. For this reason, I can't figure out how to select the correct object for the randomly selected initial item.

Comment: @ WyWyGuy I can't see where the difficulty is. Define a multi-level objects structure like this: `const objL4 = {"name": "4thLayer"}; const objL3 = {"1stObjL4": objL4}; const objL2 = {"1stObjL3": objL3}; const objL1 = {"1stObjL2": objL2};` And with `objL1["1stObjL2"]["1stObjL3"]["1stObjL4"]["name"]` you got `"4thLayer"`. If the depth is a constant, you just set strings in `[ ]` as variables in previous expression then you can select objects dynamically.

Comment: @ SdtElectronics Ah, I see my problem. My objects are defined with thee values as strings rather than referring to other objects. I see my issue now. However, a follow up problem has arisen. I have 2 lines of code to pick a random property from an object, but when the values aren't strings, it returns undefined rather than the object. How can I fix this? Here are the two lines I'm using:      var keys = Object.keys(theObject);    
      randomSelection = theObject[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];

Comment: @ SdtElectronics Nevermind, I figured it out. You defined them in reverse order because otherwise it will return undefined, as the lowest category must be defined first for the other objects to register them. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ WyWyGuy You are welcome. If your question is solved please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is use `switch` statements and map to corresponding array.

```js
mainArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];

item1Array = ["1"];
item2Array = ["2"];
item3Array = ["3"];
item4Array = ["4"];
item5Array = ["5"];

function choose() {
  var choice1 = mainArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * mainArray.length)];
  let result = [];
  switch(choice1) {
    case "item1":
      result = item1Array;
      break;
    case "item2":
      result = item2Array;
      break;
    case "item3":
      result = item3Array;
      break;
    case "item4":
      result = item4Array;
      break;
    case "item5":
      result = item5Array;
      break;
    default:
      result = [];
      break;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(choose());
console.log(choose());
```

Alternatively, Build an object with key as item and value as array

```js
mainArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];

item1Array = ["1"];
item2Array = ["2"];
item3Array = ["3"];
item4Array = ["4"];
item5Array = ["5"];


function choose2() {
  var choice1 = mainArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * mainArray.length)];
  const result = {
    item1: item1Array,
    item2: item2Array,
    item3: item3Array,
    item4: item4Array,
    item5: item5Array,
  }
  return result[choice1];
}

console.log(choose2());
console.log(choose2());
```